# Commonly-occurring clouds below a forest canopy

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, flora

What physical attributes of atmosphere and flora could cause clouds to form on a regular basis below the canopy of a forest between one-fourth and one-half the height of the forest, without impacting the global norm of high-altitude clouds (at thousands of feet)?

Assume a non-Earth environment for answers to this question; specifically, an atmosphere as described in [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9755/impact-on-the-sciences-with-helium-instead-of-nitrogen) question. If the ground composition is a factor, I have in mind a dense weave of roots a few dozen feet thick floating atop a deep ocean. The foundational plants in this composition are moss- or algae-like and extend out from a continent as a biological extension to the land area. The roots collect particles and corpses which allows for the growth of the forest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no good way to get an in-forest cloud like you describe.  Clouds form when saturated air cools to the point that it becomes supersaturated and water starts condensing out.  Forests provide an insulating blanket and disrupt winds, so the air within them is fairly uniform in temperature and humidity.

Your best bet is a [ground fog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog#Types) caused by the underlying ocean: a flow of cold water causes the forest floor to cool, creating a fog that rises from the ground upwards.  It won't normally float above the ground, though.

Comment: So I won't be able to use low-level clouds as a means to create separate classes in society. Nuts.